# Area covered by a point cloud with R

Tags: r, cloud, 2d, surface, area

I have a cloud of points scattered in a 2D Euclidean space. I would like to calculate the area inside the polygon linking the most extreme (=peripheral) points of the cloud. In other words, I would like to estimate the area covered by the cloud in this space. 
Is there a formula in R?
Thanks a lot for any response
Julien

Answer (score 16):

This is called the convex-hull problem; R built-in `chull` function should do the work. To count area, you may use a formula from [here](http://www.biostat.wustl.edu/archives/html/s-news/2001-04/msg00047.html).

EDIT: Even better; `splancs` package has `areapl` function. So the function solving your problem should look like this:

```
cha<-function(x,y){
chull(x,y)->i
return(areapl(cbind(x[i],y[i])))
}
```

For instance:

```
library(splancs);
x<-rnorm(20);rnorm(20)->y;
#Some visualization
i<-chull(x,y);plot(x,y);polygon(x[i],y[i]);
#The area
cha(x,y);
```

Comment: `rgeos::gArea` works with classes created to handle spatial problems (see package `sp`). Might be worth exploring in that direction.