# Draw All Lines Between Points

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I have the following R code

```
x <- c(0.01848598, 0.08052353, 0.06741172, 0.11652034)
y <- c(0.4177541, 0.4042247, 0.3964025, 0.4074685)
d <- data.frame(x,y)

ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point(size=4)
```

It creates the following graph:

[image: RPoints]

I would like to draw all possible lines between these points in a repeatable way, ie the number, location, etc of the points may change.  Does anyone know of a R function to do something like this.  The standard +geom_point() only draws lines between subsequent points on the x axis. My ideal output is shown below.  Thanks in advance.

[image: RPoints with lines]

**BONUS** - Does anyone know of a metric (preferably available in R) to estimate the volume of space a set of points takes up?  In this case the set of space contained by the outer triangle.

**EDIT** - Bonus has already been answered in a different SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672260/area-covered-by-a-point-cloud-with-r)

Comment: @JHowlX The bonus is really a separate question.  It's interesting in its own right.  Could you delete as a bonus and re-ask as a new question where it's less likely to be missed and conforms to the help center guidelines.

Comment: @Tyler Rinker Great suggestion, I was worried the bonus was not really a SO programming question but more of a math problem BUT as I was taking you advice and writing it up in SO, I found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672260/area-covered-by-a-point-cloud-with-r).  I haven't verified it works yet but certainly looks promising!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could always do a transformation to create all the segments you want to plot yourself

```
x <- c(0.01848598, 0.08052353, 0.06741172, 0.11652034)
y <- c(0.4177541, 0.4042247, 0.3964025, 0.4074685)
d <- data.frame(x,y)

idx <- combn(1:length(x), 2)
dd <- data.frame(x=x[idx[1,]],y=y[idx[1,]], xend=x[idx[2,]], yend=y[idx[2,]])

ggplot(d,aes(x,y)) + 
    geom_point(data=d) + 
    geom_segment(data=dd, aes(xend=xend, yend=yend))
```

which results in

[image]