# How calculate the area of a polygon in R, if I only have X,Y coordinates?

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I have a data frame with X, Y coordinates, but I need to calculate the area that cover all the points in the [scatterplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2jja.png)
there is a way to draw a polygon that surround all the points and calculate this area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a convex hull problem. [Other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672260/area-covered-by-a-point-cloud-with-r) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48690755/adding-convex-hull-to-ggplot-map) cover similar territory. We can gather the plotting and area calculation problems here for good measure.

To plot the convex hull of a point cloud, we can use the `chull` function:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(x = runif(50), y = runif(50))

convex_hull <- data %>% slice(chull(x, y))

ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_polygon(data = convex_hull,
               alpha = 0.25)
```

[image: 2D convex hull]

Library `splancs` has an `areapl` function to calculate the area of a non-selfintersecting polygon, such as the `convex_hull` above. Hence, we may do:

```
library(splancs)
as.matrix(convex_hull) %>% areapl
```